# Change album art on Android Q

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

The app provides the ability to change the album art of an album using the following method:

```
                        Uri albumArtUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
                        Uri idAlbumArtUdi = ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, albumId);

                        {
                            // First set _data to null
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.putNull("_data");

                            final String selection = "album_id=?";
                            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(albumId)};
                            final int updatedCount = resolver.update(
                                    idAlbumArtUdi,
                                    values,
                                    selection,
                                    selectionArgs);

                            if (updatedCount == 0) {
                                ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues(values);
                                newValues.put("album_id", albumId);
                                Uri uri = resolver.insert(albumArtUri, newValues);
                            }
                        }

                        if (filepath != null) {
                            // then insert filepath into _data if it's notl null
                            ContentValues insertionValues = new ContentValues();
                            insertionValues.put("_data", filepath);

                            final String selection = "album_id=?";
                            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(albumId)};
                            resolver.update(idAlbumArtUdi, insertionValues, selection, selectionArgs);
                        } else {
                            // It was a deletion so we don't insert anything here
                        }

                        resolver.notifyChange(idAlbumArtUdi, null);
```

It works perfectly on all Android version until the API 29.
On the SDK API 29 it throws a NullPointerException in this line of the code:

```
                          final int updatedCount = resolver.update(
                                    idAlbumArtUdi,
                                    values,
                                    selection,
                                    selectionArgs);
```

I know there are changes in Android Q and album arts should be loaded using ContentResolver.loadThumbnail method. But I want to change the album art and didn't find any method for that. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't access the data column anymore

Comment: @greywolf82 It seems so. Do you have any idea how album arts are stored in the media store in API 29 and how we can change them?

Comment: @greywolf82 _data has been deprecated but can still be used. File io is now using the storage access framework saf. I am struggling with this myself

Comment: @AlexeiArtsimovich Found a solution for this?

Comment: @Theo Did you find a way to do this? I'm struggling too with these api changes. How can we update an album art without the data column which is now deprecated?

Comment: @VinceVD it is impossible in new Api. The only way is to store image in app's (external or internal) storage and save the path to image somewhere in app's db

Comment: @AlexeiArtsimovich But where do i store this path now? Before Api 29 i used a ContentResolver with ContentValues where i store the file path from image in the data column (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA) which is now deprecated so what do we use now to store it? Can you show some example code about what you mean with "save the path to image somewhere in app's db"

Comment: @VinceVD I mean you can't store the path of the file using the MediaStore.
But you can save it in your database in a table, lets name it 'AlbumArts', so that there are two columns in the table: long albumId and string file_path. That's it.
And then whenever you want to get the file path of the album art of the album with the specified id you query it in your database.
The problem is that only you will have access to this, but other apps will not know anything about it

Answer (score 0):

The content://media/external/audio/albumart thing just works but it is indeed a dirty hack.

Maybe google just don't want you to change it from the very bottom so they deprecated the column and banned us from accessing the corresponding DB parts.

I think changing the embedded album cover would be the thing to do (yet nasty)